# Given sets A and B, is there a standard library function to generate the 3-ple (A - B, intersection, B - A)?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

That is, I'm looking for a standard or quasi-standard (Apache Commons, Guava, etc.) library function that will efficiently produce this:

```
def f[T](oldSet: Set[T], newSet: Set[T]): (Set[T], Set[T], Set[T]) = {
    val removed = oldSet.diff(newSet)
    val kept = oldSet.intersect(newSet)
    val added = newSet.diff(oldSet)
    (removed, kept, added)
}
```

Obviously this isn't hard to write, and I'm sure I could make a more or less optimal implementation without much effort, but the need for this has come up often enough for me that I'm baffled that there doesn't seem to be a well-known library function to do this. Am I missing something, or does it really not exist?

EDIT: For those who are pointing me to Scala's standard intersect and diff functions and their operator equivalents, I appreciate the thought, but I already know about these, as you can see from the fact that I use them in the example above. I'm looking for a standard library function that is functionally equivalent to and more efficient than the function f() defined above.

Comment: Unfortunately, comments cant contain lmgtfy, but look up: scala set intersection ;)

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set@intersect(that:scala.collection.GenSet[A]):Repr

Comment: Are you talking about the intersect() method that I use in the example  above? I'm looking for an operation that will produce the intersection and both differences (A - B) and (B - A) in a single call. I believe that the code above is less than optimal, and that a function specifically designed to produce all three sets could do better.

Comment: I think this is such a specific task that having a library method for it would be considered code bloat to include in general library. Especially since it is so easy to write

Comment: It's difficult to see why you'd expect this to be a standard function. Standard functions tend to be either basic operations or common ones. This does not seem to me like it would be either of these. You might also expect this to be a standard function if there is an algorithm that is known to produce just this tuple more efficiently than some combination of basic operations. (this would then be something like a basic operation). Does such an algorithm exist, in your knowledge? If not, the combination is obvious, and YAGNI suggests it should not be in the standard libraries.

Answer (score 5):

There is not such a function in the Scala standard library.  But doing it the "hard way" is only about twice as slow as doing it the "efficient way", so I would recommend not worrying about it.

(`a partition b` can be used to produce `(a & b, a diff b)`.)

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing it (not claiming that it is the best, or even that it is good) is to write a function that returns 3 different values, depending on which of the result sets a given element should be in, and then just `groupBy` the union of both sets using that function